# Frequent request failures/time outs in a background service

Tags: c#, android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-location

So I have an application that starts a service which does location geofencing goodness and sends HTTP request to a server for the user to do things with.  When my app's service gets a "Entered/Exited location region" event it fires off an HTTP request.  Things are working well overall.  *But i'm having an issue where the Http request I make in the background service doesn't have a very high success rate*.  When i'm running the app in the foreground it tends to succeed 95-100% of the time.  When the app is killed and only the service is running it tends to succeed around 80% of the time.  The other 20% of the time it either times out or fails, almost as if it doesn't have an internet connection or something.  I have a retry system built in for the event in which it fails/times out.  I've noticed that when it fails/times out, it will retry and fail/time out 1-4 times in a row before succeeding several minutes later.  This results in a delayed message delivery.

Has anyone encountered this?  Is it normal?  Or is there something I can do to increase the likelihood that my 1st request will succeed rather than having to wait through many retries?

**So a location test run may like this:**

- Kill the app (service starts and runs fine)
- Leave office, request succeeds
- Enter home, request succeeds
- Leave home, request succeeds
- Enter library, request timesout, retry request fails, retry request succeeds.  The result is that the message saying "Entered library" is a few minutes late.
- Exit library, request succeeds
- Enter office, request succeeds

With the app running in the foreground it's significantly less likely to timeout/fail.

Had some formatting issues copy/pasting this code in, so here's a screenie:
[image]

```
                // Create a request
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(this.Method, new Uri(url));
                request.Headers.Clear();
                this.Body = string.Empty;

                // Serialize request data for the body
                if (a_requestData != null)
                {
                    this.Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a_requestData);
                    request.Content = new StringContent(this.Body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                }

                // Add headers
                request.Headers.Add(……..);

                // More code I left out to simplify

                // Using SendAsync
                result = httpClient.SendAsync(request, this.RestCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

Comment: "Is it normal?" -- on Android 6.0+ devices, yes, while the device is in Doze mode or your app is in app standby mode.

Comment: Ahhh I see.  So Doze mode is on by default.  Is that typically true for all devices? I wasn't aware of that.  So looking up the docs on that, I see "To ensure a great experience for your users, you should test your app fully in Doze and App Standby."  Since it's on by default, handling this will be critical.

Comment: "Is that typically true for all devices?" -- Android 6.0+, yes. Older devices may have similar sorts of battery-saving modes implemented by device manufacturers.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you are calling and creating this AsyncTask inside of a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @PabloBaxter yes

Comment: I'm also guessing you are using Google's Geofencing API, so have you tried registering your geofence using an IntentService vs a BroadcastReceiver, and handling all your HTTP logic within the onHandleIntent function?

Comment: So the app that I currently have deployed in google play is using a BroadcastReceiver with OnHandleIntent, which makes the HTTP request.  I've been testing and comparing with an alternative (which is actually working better surprisingly) It's not using Android's geofencing at all and instead just polling location and putting my logic in OnLocationChanges.  I'm storing my regions in the keychain and doing the enter/exit logic myself based on lat/longs.  But in both cases, i've seen a fair amount of these HTTP requests failing or timing out.

Comment: The thing about a BroadcastReceiver is that it will die once it finishes the "onReceive" method, making your AsyncTask eligible to be garbage collected. The reason I mentioned IntentService is that it runs everything in the "onHandleIntent" function in the background first, then kills the service created once it has completed. As far as your custom geofence solution, kudos! Just watch that battery drain!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'll keep it in mind going forward.  The custom one is using ~2% battery on high accuracy (apparently with Doze mode turned on) with 4 geofences, so not too shabby.  The main reason I've gone custom is because my user's and I were seeing lots of region "flip flopping" in a 300 meter radius (aka Lots of enters and exits despite sitting still on wifi).  So I'm smoothing the flip flopping at a location level rather at the onHandleIntent level.  Also regarding battery, i'm going to adjust my location polling frequency based on distance from nearest region.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138156/discussion-between-pablo-baxter-and-lampshade).